# Compare values in a list of maps in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have a list of maps like

```
       (def listofmaps
       ({:directory_path "/some/path/1", :directory_size "8.49 GB"} {:directory_path "/user/dod/yieldbook/yb_sec_char", :directory_size "14.1 MB"})
```

containing many values and size can be in gb or mb.

Also I have a limitlistofmaps like

```
     (def limitlistofmaps
     ({:directory_path "/some/path/8", :directory_size "15.2 GB"}  {:directory_path "some/path/3", :directory_size "2.1 GB"}
     {:directory_path "/some/path/1", :directory_size "17.2 GB"})
```

with many values..

I need to print "limit exceeded" if any map in list of maps had the same :directory_path as in limitlistofmaps but :directory_size exceeds the value specified. The problem is that size is in string format and unit has to be considered.

Can you help me with a way to do this in clojure?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use regex like http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-seq to pull out the number and units from the size string, then parse the number with parseDouble:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why people down voted your question. I think as a Clojure community we are much better. I'm also a Clojure newb and I have nothing but great things to say about the community. I would like that it stays this way.

Firstly, why not have all the directory sizes in the same unit ? That way it's easier to compare them, say in KB.

Here is one version of a function that would transform any string like "100.23 Gb", "12 B", "123.3443 MB" to a Double representing Kilobytes.

```
(defn convert-to-kb
  "Converts a string 'number (B|KB|MB|GB)' to Double representing KBytes"
  [str]
  (let [[number-str unit] (map str/lower-case (str/split (str/trim str) #"\s+"))
        number (Double/parseDouble number-str)]
    (condp = unit
      "b"  (/ number 1000)
      "kb" number
      "mb" (* number 1000)
      "gb" (* number 1000000))))
```

Secondly, I would suggest you put the directory size limits in the same map data that lives inside your **listofmaps**, so you don't have state duplication like you have now in **limitslistofmaps**. But if for some reason you need this second map, here a piece of ugly code that returns a list of maps that are the same as in your **listofmaps** with two added key/val entries, :max_size_kb and :directory_size_kb.

```
for [dir listofmaps :let [{:keys [directory_path directory_size]} dir]]
  (let [limit-map (first
                    (get (group-by :directory_path limitlistofmaps) directory_path))
        max-size-kb (convert-to-kb (:directory_size limit-map))]
    (-> dir
        (assoc :max_size_kb max-size-kb)
        (assoc :directory_size_kb (convert-to-kb directory_size)))))
```